# Add shortcut in keyboard settings through app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, settings.bundle

In default `settings app` we can add keyboard shortcuts for a phrase or word manually, that will work as auto-complete while typing like this -

[image]

i want to add a word in default iPhone dictionary so that when user start entering text it will auto-complete.

is there any way to do this through app ?

Comment: You could check this http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextChecker_Class/Reference/Reference.html and get this done.