# iOS Keyboard Shortcuts programmatically

Tags: ios

Is there any way iOS keyboard shortcuts [Settings > General > keyboard] can be added or deleted programmatically or with plists. I do understand Apps are written in Sandboxed environment without any api's for the settings app except the settings bundle. Is there a way this can be achieved without jailbreaking the iOS device. Are there approved private libraries? The apps will not be pushed to apple app store.

Any info is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know your app won't be accepted if you use private libs. 
And I don't suggest jailbreaking as a market strategy either :)
So maybe you could find a nice workaround to your problem.
give a look to this post

[how can i make custom keyboard shortcut for frequently used phrases in ios6 #ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13114248/how-can-i-make-custom-keyboard-shortcut-for-frequently-used-phrases-in-ios6-ios)

Comment: From the question: `The apps will not be pushed to apple app store.`

Comment: Yep, no apple app store just the private app store - MAM